# Python output is blank when i execute the following code:

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

This program is a banking system. It connects to an online database which contains customer details and transaction details. However, when I execute the code, I get a blank output in python 3.4.0 shell:

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                            'Server=***;'
                            'Database=***;'
                            'uid=***;pwd=***')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

def MainMenu():
    print('##############################\n\tWelcome to the XYZ Banking System\n##############################')
    print()
    print('PLEASE ENTER THE NUMBER CORRESPONDING TO YOUR DESIRED COMMAND IN THE PROMPT BELOW : \n\t1.ACCESS CUSTOMER DETAILS\n\t2.ACCESS TRANSACTION PORTAL\n##############################')
    print()
    var_UserInput=input('>>>')
        if var_UserInput=='1':
            return CustomerPortal()

def CustomerPortal():
    cursor.tables()
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print (row.customer)

MainMenu()
```

Comment: Your indentation is messed up. That code won't run at all; it will produce an `IndentationError`.

Comment: Are you posting proprietary code on SO?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not at all. Appreciate your concern though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I've made a few changes:

- Moved the connection string into the function
- Modified the code to be closer to PEP-8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/
- Fixed indentation

Here's the code.

```
import pyodbc


def main_menu():
    print('##############################\n\tWelcome to the XYZ Banking System\n##############################')
    print()
    print('PLEASE ENTER THE NUMBER CORRESPONDING TO YOUR DESIRED COMMAND IN THE PROMPT BELOW : \n\t1.ACCESS CUSTOMER DETAILS\n\t2.ACCESS TRANSACTION PORTAL\n##############################')
    print()
    var_user_input=input('>>>')
        if var_user_input=='1':
            return customer_portal()

def customer_portal():
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                                'Server=***;'
                                'Database=***;'
                                'uid=***;pwd=***')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.tables()
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print (row.customer)
    cursor.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_menu()
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. It was indeed an issue with indentation. Plus I also made some other modifications, such as creating a class called Menu, and creating other menus using that class constructor. Now everything seems to be in order :-)

Comment: Great! Can you mark the answer correct? Sounds like you are on the right path!